# resolve docker network alias from multiple networks

Tags: docker

Consider following scenario. I have 2 containers on 2 different networks with the same alias *app*.

```bash
# create 2 networks
$ docker network create net1
$ docker network create net2
# create a container in each network with the same alias
$ docker run --name app1 -d --rm --network net1 --network-alias app bluebrown/echoserver
$ docker run --name app2 -d --rm --network net2 --network-alias app bluebrown/echoserver
```

Now, I am running a third container that is connected to both networks and query the DNS resolver for the alias *app*.

```bash
# create the dig container and join to both networks
$ docker run --name dig --rm -d  bluebrown/netutils sleep inf
$ docker network connect net1 dig
$ docker network connect net2 dig
# query for the alias app
$ docker exec dig sh -ec 'seq 5 | xargs -I -- dig +short app'
172.26.0.2
172.26.0.2
172.26.0.2
172.26.0.2
172.26.0.2
```

I did expect to get DNS round-robin from this kind of setup. Meaning, dig should get 2 A records back. Since, is connected to both networks and can resolve the apps by their names.

```bash
$ docker exec dig dig +short app1 app2
172.26.0.2
172.27.0.2
```

The above output shows that when using the alias for the query, only app1 is resolved. It seems like because it was the network the *dig* container was connected to first.

Is there a way to solve this, or at least specify in which network I am looking for the alias? And is the above behavior deterministic?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this question?

Comment: @Ashley, no. I have also asked in the docker slack channel but didn't receive an answer. Perhaps I should file and issue on GitHub.

Comment: I ended up just giving the container a specific alias on that network; that way I can ensure resolution of that name will always be across that network.